# Using beautifulSoup to get listings

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a url using Python/BeautifulSoup. Below is my code. I am just wondering if there's a better to get a sorted dictionary without using two lists? Or is there any efficient way?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

req = requests.get('https://www.firstchampionship.org/sponsorvideos')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

companies = []
votes = []
all_in_one = {}

for company in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "views-field views-field-title"}):
    # print(company.text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    companies.append(company.text.encode('ascii','ignore'))

for vote in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rate-info"}):     
    vote_x = vote.text.split(" ")
    votes.append(int(vote_x[0]))

for i, x in enumerate(companies):
    all_in_one.update({x:votes[i]})

for key, value in all_in_one.iteritems():
    print(key+"->"+str(value))

sorted_x = sorted(all_in_one.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(sorted_x)
```

My final is like below. Company name-> Num of votes

> [(' Analog Devices ', 7227), (' Bechtel ', 6797), (' NVIDIA ', 436),
>   (' Qualcomm Incorporated ', 349), (' ViaSat ', 292), (' BOSCH ', 201),
>   (' Nokia Bell Labs ', 124), (' Walt Disney Imagineering ', 119), ('
>   Google, Inc. ', 113), (' NI ', 109), (' FedEx ', 100), (' NASA ', 97),
>   (' The Boeing Company ', 86), (' U.S. Air Force ', 83), (' FIRST ',
>   74), (' 3M Company ', 73), (' Twitch ', 73), (' Baxter ', 70), ('
>   Rockwell Automation ', 68), (' Booz Allen Hamilton ', 68), (' NRG ',
>   66), (' Mouser Electronics ', 63), (' IBM Corporation ', 63), (' John
>   Deere ', 63), (' Motorola Solutions ', 62), (' Delphi ', 62), ('
>   Boston Scientific ', 60), (' Texas Instruments ', 59), (' The Dow
>   Chemical Co. ', 59), (' PTC ', 59), (' Xerox ', 58), (' Southwest
>   Airlines ', 57), (' GM ', 55), (' Vulcan Spring ', 53), (' Rockwell
>   Collins ', 52), (' Festo ', 52), (' Monsanto ', 50), (' LEGO Education
>   ', 39)]

Comment: What do you mean by a sorted dictionary? Dictionaries are un-ordered by definition.

Comment: This is a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Priyank, yes dict's are unordered , but I am interested in knowing if I can eliminate the use of two lists and get a dict

Comment: @Priyank or let me put it this way, if you had the opportunity,  what would you change if at all in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the **company title**, get the **parent node**, find the next element which match the votes node, append it to a **list** as a **dict** and **order** it by the company name.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from operator import itemgetter

req = requests.get('https://www.firstchampionship.org/sponsorvideos')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

companies = []

for company in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "views-field views-field-title"}):
    companies.append({"Company": company.get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii','ignore'), "Votes": company.parent.find_next("div", class_="rate-info").get_text(strip=True).split(' ')[0]})

print (sorted(companies, key=itemgetter('Company')))
```

Output:

> [{'Company': '3M Company', 'Votes': u'76'}, {'Company': 'Analog Devices', 'Votes': u'7282'}...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter from the collections library.

```
from collection import Counter

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.firstchampionship.org/sponsorvideos')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

counts = Counter()

companies = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "views-field views-field-title"})
votes = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rate-info"})

for company, vote in zip(companies, votes):
    company_name = company.text.encode('ascii','ignore')
    vote_count = int(vote.text.split(" ")[0])
    counts[company_name] = vote_count

for company_name, vote_count in counts.most_common():
    print(company_name, vote_count)
```